# Newbie ?: is this a variable, function, or what?

Tags: python, function, variables

I'm new to python and am trying to write an equation that draws upon several values for an automated process. These are populations constants. So for example,

```
Pop1Stnd=78784000 

Pop2Stnd=150486000

Pop3Stnd=45364000
```

Would this be sufficient in its present form to declare at the top of the script, i.e. (and I'm using arcpy) below import arcpy, set.env.workspace etc.

If not, do I need to declare it in another way? 
Perhaps

```
def Pop1Stnd=78784000
```

Lastly, is the present phrasing a function, a variable, or what?
many thanks,
david

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the first way is how you declare a variable and is perfectly fine, however typically when declaring a constant, style dictates to use all caps like:

```
POP1STND = 78784000
```

The second way with:

```
def Pop1Stnd=78784000
```

would be for defining a function although the syntax is incorrect/incomplete. It would be something like:

```
def pop_function("paramaters go here"):
    "do some stuff here"
```

Comment: I'd vote this up but i don't have the street cred! Many thanks though!

Comment: Accept the answer if it solved the problem.  Generally though, a question like you asked would be closed since the answer could be found in the Python documentation or any number or tutorials, or by looking at numerous python related questions on SO.

Comment: @DavidMeek it's worth noting that style-wise, constants are normally written in all uppercase - eg: `POP1STDN`

Comment: @Jon Clements, adding that to my answer.

Comment: @JonClements many thanks for the edification :)